# How to close bootstrap model popup automatically if not available data in model popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Here I'm using bootstrap model, in that model I have some bootstrap cards but every card have a close button if I hit on the close button the card will hide/removed from the bootstrap model popup when model popup have only one card and if I want close that last card also now this time i want to close model popup also  automatically. but i am not able to achieve it. any one can please help on me it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      .modal-body{
        height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 1</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2 ">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 2</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 3</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 4</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
                
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clscurrent').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('.removeit').remove();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
      .modal-body{
        height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 1</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2 ">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 2</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 3</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body 4</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
                
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="card removeit mb-2">
            <div class="card-header"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Card body</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent ml-2">Done</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent">Skip</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clscurrent').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('.removeit').remove();
      if($("#myModal").find('div.card').length==0)
        {
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        }
      
});
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your modal length is not available or less than one then you can apply this

```
$('#modal_name').modal('hide')
```

using jQuery to hide the modal
Hope it will help you.